# nginx server_name regex before exact match

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I want to implement a LetsEncrypt acme-challenge location statement globally for any server_name which ever will be requested.

So I wrote the following server block :

```
server {
        server_name ~^(.+)$;
        listen 80;

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                default_type "text/plain";
                root        /etc/nginx/ssl/le;
                allow all;
        }
}
```

From what I think I know, I understand that if there is an exact match of a server-block, my server-block above will not be invoked.

Is there any trick how to accomplish it without ever touching the actual server-blocks of the domains?

I'm even fine with an if-statement

Comment: I have tested your configuration and also according with http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html this block code will not be invoked if exist the "real" domain name
As of now I am copying the "acme-challenge" code into my vhosts ...

Comment: yeah that's what I already said and admitted. My question is, how to trick around that. because you must agree that you can not touch or edit hundrets of absolutely differently layouted vhost configs to fill in that code on the right place with less effort. It must be possible to implement that code in a global manner.

Comment: For now I only can imagine to put that code into a file and include it in the vhosts. The problem is that the right place for the include is not always the same. Actually I prefer not to touch the vhosts at all.

Comment: Thinking about some kind of global if-statement like "if requested url is like .well-known/acme-challenge ; include acme-snippet"

Comment: An easy way to hack this is to setup a global http -> https on the `:80` `default_server` as well as serving the `.well-known`. Since validation will hit the http endpoint, you'll verify your domains, while redirecting to https and keeping your https vhosts intact. This is based upon the assumption that you only serve https and don't need the http vhosts for anything other than redirecting to https.

Comment: not possible since every domain has it's own http-block